# Report phishing attempt on Twitter

Tags: twitter, phishing

I think a friend's Twitter account has been compromised. She has sent me a direct message with a link which is an obvious phishing attempt to get my password.

I didn't fall for it, and I sent a message back to my friend that her account may have been compromised. Even if the message didn't actually come from her and was spoofed in some other way, I still want to report it to Twitter so that they can detect other messages using the same link.

The [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com) isn't particularly helpful in this regard. How can I report this to them? Can one even forward a Twitter DM?

Comment: Have you tried https://twitter.com/Support ?

Comment: No, but I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site should send you to the appropriate form to report phishing http://twitter.com/help/escalate

Specifically, have your friend fill out the "[Account hacked](http://support.twitter.com/forms/hacked)" form.

Comment: Yeah, been there. It's just a wall of links. The closes I can find is the one for spam. It's not very helpful.

Comment: The one about harassment might help

Comment: Ok, get your friend to fill out [this form](http://support.twitter.com/forms/hacked).

Comment: After filling out the form, all they had her do was change her password and disconnect any connected apps.

Comment: Ask her to run a full anti-virus scan on her computer, even if she has a Mac